# "enough" and "a lot of" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

> 1. The earthquake is strong enough to cause **a lot of** damage.
> 2. The earthquake is strong enough to cause damage.

I am quite keen to know whether I can use
"enough" and " a lot of" in a sentence.

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. Why do you think that it may be incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Both of the proposed sentences are fine in standard English.

Typically, with regard to earthquakes, there is usually some mention of *a degree* of damage, so sentence #1 would be more likely to be used than sentence #2. You might also encounter sentences such as:

The earthquake was not strong enough to cause any damage.

The earthquake was strong enough to cause a moderate amount of damage.

The earthquake was strong enough to cause a very severe amount of damage.